# Модальное окно

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите собираюсь сделать что бы на каждой странице пользователя находилась к кнопка при нажатии которой создается форма в модальном окне для отправки сообщения.

```
    function createBlock(){
    var block = document.createElement('div');
    block.className = 'overlay'
    block.innerHTML = 'код'
    document.body.appendChild(block);
}
```

вот сам код который будет создавать элемент и тд подскажите что надо добавить перед ним что бы экран затемнялся перед созданием формы  ? возможно ли создание элемента сделать анимированным ? + весь код формы придется писать в block.innerHTML ?или можно код как то  вставить туда из стороннего файла ?Заранее спасибо!(если есть прощу вариант то подскажите какой нибудь скрипт модального окна который будет работать под jquery 1.5.2 тк проект стоит на нем)

Comment: А почему такая привязка к jQuery версии 1.5.2? Это принципиально и не подлежит редактированию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть у меня [старый примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/45hUE/1/). Я его чуть адаптировал под версию 1.5.2 и вроде как работает нормально. Кое-что там лишнее, но думаю, то, что вам нужно - найдёте. Для подгрузки в модальное окно внешнего документа (или часть его), можно использовать или же [$.ajax()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81), в частности, вам подойдёт метод [.load()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), или же использовать iframe.

Comment: Спасибо!А как сделать так что бы это модальное окно становилось по центру страницы,центрировалось ?

Comment: Если финальные размеры вам известны и задаете их сами, то можно сделать [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/45hUE/2/). Если же размеры не известны, то необходимо "проявить" объект, высчитать его размеры и также, как в примере выше, подставить значения в формулу. Для более точной подгонки, надо учитывать погрешности (margin, padding, border etc.) у элементов.

Comment: просто я для проекта писал стену,но в ней есть нюанс которы с версиями старше не дает ей работать корректно,то есть не выводит аяксом данные,то есть сообщения пользователя ... сейчас буду думать как это исправить,а то с 1.5.2 далеко как я понимаю не уедешь ?

Comment: Пс когда я вставил в свой проект модальное окно то оно  открывается все нормально но при нажатии на фон не скрывается(